# sending data from mysql table to list of mailchimp campaign is it possible?

Tags: mailchimp

I am using Mailchimp campaign to send emails but when i tried to save data in the list from my sql with laravel hit they just blocked my account any solution of this you can see the screenshot. [image]

Comment: Take it up with them.  We're not Mailchimp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contact their Developers and use contact forum You will get the solution by them may be your account is not supporting their terms and conditions.They are always on monday to friday

Comment: ok i will try. But they can answer in a day ?

Comment: Yes may be they can.